# How can I add scrolling to a <div> if the contents of the <div> are too big to fit?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following  with AngularJS:

```
<div style="width: 725px; height: 200px;" 
 data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="question.text"></div>
```

Is there a way that I can add a scroll to this so that it will accept any size of contents:

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` to the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow-y` and a fixed `height`.
This will add scrolling to the div.

**For instance**

```
<div style="width: 725px; height: 200px; overflow-y:scroll;" data-ng-bind-html-unsafe="question.text">
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your container (`div`) already has a fixed height, so use the css property `overflow-y: scroll`. Note that it is not supported in IE < 8.